# Travelling to Canada. Name mismatch on Visa and Passport

Tags: passports, canada, tourist-visas

My parents will be travelling to Canada this June. They got their Visas and will now be booking their tickets. We noticed this discrepancy in my dad's passport and visa:

His name is **Gulshan Pal** in all his identity proofs. The passport has no Surname and the Given name says **Gulshan Pal**. While the Canadian tourist visa on the passport does not have a Given name and the surname says **Gulshan Pal**.

Now while booking tickets it's become extremely confusing as to what is to be given for the first and last name. The customer care executives gave a few workarounds but we're not sure and do not want to get into some trouble after reaching Canada.

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: The visa is attached on the same passport? In that case it is obvious that the person it is the same (and possibly it is just a problem of Canada databases, where surname must exists. The official name is on Passport, so you should use that for the ticket. You will give later also the passport number (which is unique) so they [immigration/security] know who he is.

Comment: [PS: depending on airline and website, good luck on giving just name and not surname; which is completely legit, but for mane programmers]

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely use the name as on the official identifying document, your passport.
It could be worth a call to the issuing embassy or consulate. Sometimes it's possible to call the port of entry in Canada, but that's going to be harder, and the answers may be non-binding and advice-oriented.
Oh and then you have to confirm with the airline that they're okay with this being a mismatch between your passport and visa for the purposes of checkin and boarding.